# PHP 'Count' displaying multiple '1's and not a total value

Tags: php, sql, database, count

I am calling data from an SQL database in PHP, and I want to be able to count the number of specific values I am pulling from the database, I can pull a specific value, and get say 20 values, when I try to get the 'Count' of these values, it'll display 20 '1's so "11111111111111111111" rather than "20".

I have tried printing it, and entering it into a table, and neither produce the result I want.

My code below:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$conn = new mysqli("xxx.xxx.xxx","title","password","title");
if (!$con){
    {exit("Connection Failed: " . $con);}
    //Connecting to the (DB) Database
}


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<table>
<tr><td><strong>Count</strong></td></tr>
<?php
$start=$_POST['start'];
$end=$_POST['end'];

$sql="SELECT Data.Items ".
//Selecting the required data from the table
$sql="FROM Data ";
//Selecting FROM the Table(s) required


$reports = $con->query($sql);

while ($report = $reports->fetch_object()){
    $result = count ($report->Items);

    echo count ($result);

    echo "<tr><td>".$report->Items."</td></tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: fetch all, then count, or just do a num rows outside of the loop. In the loop, you are counting a single rows which will always be one. **Edit:** What is in `Items`?

Comment: Use mysqli_num_rows: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are using the count function inside a loop as you fetch each row. Each row has got 1 item(which is not even an array). You have to use

```
echo $reports->num_rows;
```

before the while loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take an array with values and count how much time each value is there in database:

You can do this by using [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
$items = [];
while ($report = $reports->fetch_object()){
 $items[] = $report->Items;
}

if (! empty($items)) {
 $numOccurances = array_count_values($items);
 foreach ($numOccurances as $val => $count) {
   echo "<tr><td>" . $count . " times </td><td> => ".$val."</td></tr>";
 }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
4 times     => item 1
2 times     => item 2
1 times     => item 3
1 times     => item 5
2 times     => item 6
```